# Making individual comparisons?

Tags: python, class, dependency-injection, average

Hi all a little help if you  may assist in any way.

I have data sets

```
Name, Age, 

Mark, 19, 
John, 19, 
Jess, 25, 
Jonty, 21,
```

I run a calculation that compares a distance to work to get this data

Distance to Work(km)
    20
    25
    30
    40

What I want to do is associate these back to each name. Do I do this using a list or a class structure thing?? This is the output I want.

```
Mark, 19, 20
John, 19, 25
Jess, 25, 30
Jonty, 21, 40
```

Secondly I want to know is it possible to compare these values and make an average Lets say I have a `maxdist = 35`

Can It be written to compare all these dist to max distance and then take the values that appear.

```
Mark, 19, 20
John, 19, 25
Jess, 25, 30
```

and calculate an average age?? I.e to get 21??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're always in the same order, you could do something crude like this - I would say classes are an overkill:

```
>>> people = [
... ('Mark', 19,) ,
... ('John', 19, ),
... ('Jess', 25, ),
... ('Jonty', 21,)]
>>>
>>> to_work = map(int, '20 25 30 40'.split())
>>> result = []
>>> ages = []
>>> for index, person in enumerate(people):
...     name, age = person
...     result.append((name, age, to_work[index]))
...     ages.append(age)
...
>>> print '\n'.join(map(str, result))
('Mark', 19, 20)
('John', 19, 25)
('Jess', 25, 30)
('Jonty', 21, 40)
>>> print 'max dist =', max(to_work)
max dist = 40
>>> print 'avg. age =', sum(ages) / len(ages)
avg. age = 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Another take:

```
people = \
[
    {"name": "Mark", "Age" : 19, "Distance" : 20},
    {"name": "John", "Age" : 19, "Distance" : 25},
    {"name": "Jess", "Age" : 25, "Distance" : 30},
    {"name": "Jonty", "Age" : 21, "Distance" : 40}
]

avg_dist = sum([person["Distance"] for person in people])/len(people)
print "Average Distance: %d" % avg_dist

lt_dist_filter = lambda dist: lambda x: x["Distance"] < dist
lt_35 = filter(lt_dist_filter(35), people)
print lt_35

avg_age = sum([person["Age"] for person in people])/len(people)
print "Average Age: %d" % avg_age
```

Comment: Hi this is cool. Can this be extended?? I.e can  you then compare the list of people and print only the people under the avearge age??

Comment: @KristoferWright, How do you know this is cool? you obviously haven't made much of an effort to understand it or you'd be able to extend it yourself

Comment: @gnibbler it looks cool. sorry?? Im thinking about it now whilst trying to understand the code so was wondering if I could extend it.

Comment: @KristoferWright, how well do you understand python or programming generally?

Comment: @dilbert not very well in general. Like I understand the basics and thats about it. Hence I am still trying to understand your code

Comment: Well, this very much seems likes an academic tutorial or homework. So it begs the question, do you want to know python or just do your tutorial ? In any case, this is basic program and uses: lists, dictionaries, list comprehensions, the sum function, the len function, the lambda function, the filter function, arithmetic comparison, string substitution and the print statement. Google these things if you want to learn more about them or play around with them in a Python console.